# Customize instalation Dialog for selection of setup files out of three or more application

Tags: windows-installer

I want to create a setup application which can have 3 application or more embedded in one setup and the installation should take place on depending upon selection of application by user.
Suppose I have 3 application "OIV", "KDL" and "IOC" built in using MFC and VC++.
Now when user install this application using setup it should popup a dialog and gives three checkbox for selection. User can select one or more checkbox and those application should get installed with there shortcuts.

I am trying with WIX Toolset. will this be helpful.
other applications are also welcome if its license free.

Answer (score 0):

I would think each application should be its own feature.  All supporting file for each application would then be under each feature.
The user can then select the feature they want to install from a standard feature selection dialogue.  This way users can also uninstall applications by just uninstalling a feature.